# Create EC2 machine with docker: not accessing credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I am trying to create a new EC2 machine using docker by using the command:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-region "us-east-1" --amazonec2-instance-type "t2.micro" rahul-test
```

I get this error:

```
Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: amazonec2 driver requires AWS credentials configured with the --amazonec2-access-key and --amazonec2-secret-key options, environment variables, ~/.aws/credentials, or an instance role
```

I have my ~/.aws/credentials, so I am not sure why the command does not use those credentials to create the machine

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
docker-machine env myenv
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX 
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXX
eval "$(docker-machine env myenv)"
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-region "us-east-1" --amazonec2-instance-type "t2.micro" rahul-test
```

[source](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/)

Comment: Ok so this let me create the machine but it failed to connect to the SSH: ```Unable to query docker version: Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint``` when iIdo docker-machine  ls under Errors

Comment: try to delete and recreate yyour VM `docker-machine rm -f NAME` and `docker-machine create -d virtualbox NAME`